# Why do I get a jQuery syntax error with .post and hide("slide")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

After I do the .post thing, I want to hide the first div with a left slide, then show the second with a right slide. My right-slide was working fine and then I went and tried to put in the left slide and I broke it all.

```
if(hasError == false) {
    $.post("/process-email-signups",{email_address: email_addressVal},
        function(data){
            $("#email_signup_form").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
                function() {
            $("#thank_you_message").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
                });
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the extra function() is doing, maybe try removing that?

```
if(hasError == false) {
    $.post("/process-email-signups",{email_address: email_addressVal},
        function(data){
                $("#email_signup_form").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
                $("#thank_you_message").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
        }
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got an extraneous function block in there.  Try this instead:

```
function(data){
                $("#email_signup_form").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 

                $("#thank_you_message").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);

                }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(hasError == false) {
    $.post("/process-email-signups", {email_address: email_addressVal},
        function(data){
                $("#email_signup_form").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
                $("#thank_you_message").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
        }
    );
}
```